# Can I Simulate My Location On My iPhone Without It Being Plugged Into XCode Real Time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, location

I understand you can download GPX files to your xCode project and plug your phone in and simulate location from there, but my question is if I can simulate my location on the go?

I want my app to have 5 different pages, each with their own GPX file and the user would use an on/off switch to activate the location simulation and deactivate the location simulation.

Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible unfortunately, you can only do that in debug mode and **not** on the go.

Comment: Thank you! I wish it was different!